# Excel table reference (structured) change to absolute range (A1) after re-opening

Tags: excel, reference, structured-references

I have a Table named `table2` on my `sheet2`, and I'm using its values on `sheet1` with the help of structured references, like:

```
=average(table2[values])
```

But after saving and re-opening the file, all my structured references are being converted to absolute references, like:

```
=average('sheet2'!$A$1:$A$5)
```

I've already readed the Help page, and made sure that the checkbox "Use Table names in formulas" is checked, and still no clue why it's happening.

Comment: @pnuts, you couldn't be more right at the "Média" translation. I've fixed the code there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The workbook I was using was from Excel 97-2003 and was set not to show "incompatible warnings".

At Excel 97-2003 mode, all structured references are changed to absolute ones.

I created another workbook to try, and found the reason.